# VBA:Run time error 6-Overflow

Tags: forms, ms-access

I want to create a MS access form that can read data from the Ms access DB. The access db has only 1 column consists of 4000 items all are integer type.It is basically item Ids. I have created a model dialog form with only one text box to search for the item id. The condition is that once i enter the value in the text box form it will compare the table id and gives the o/p as id present or not. Below is the code i have written for the same. the issue is that i am getting "Run time error 6-Overflow " once the input value matches with the table.For incorrect values the code is working fine.
Please help with this.ASAP.
The table name is table 1 and the column name is Sku.

CODE:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.Text2) Then
    MsgBox " Please Enter the Ske Id ", vbInformaton, "Sku ID Required"
    Else
        If IsNull((DLookup("Sku", "Table1", "Sku=Cint(Text2.value)"))) Then
        MsgBox "not present"

        Else
        MsgBox "present  "

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the value of `Text2.value` greater than 32767 (`2^15-1`)? i.e. Go into your immediate window and type `?cint(2^15-1)`

Comment: how can i get the value for Text2.Any ways there are total 4500 values present in the table column.

Comment: In addition to Brad's point, the criteria option for `DLookup` should create a problem: `"Sku=Cint(Text2.value)"`  I don't think the db engine will know what `Text2.value` is.

Comment: Hansup is right too, your criteria should be more like `"Sku=Cint(" & Text2.value &")"`.

Comment: As for how to get the value of Text2, that should be whatever is in the form where your control Text2 is. What are you typing in when this error occurs?

Comment: When ever i am entering the value in the form text box which is present in the table i am encountering this issue. Basically for ELse MSgBox"Present" i am getting this issue.You have any idea how i can get rid of this run time error

Comment: CAn you please help me with the entire code if possible?

Comment: Is sku a number column, or text column?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
 If IsNull(Me.Text2) Then
   MsgBox " Please Enter the Ske Id ", vbInformaton, "Sku ID Required"
 Else
    If IsNull((DLookup("Sku", "Table1", "Sku = " & me.Text2)) Then
       MsgBox "not present"
    Else
       MsgBox "present  "
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

If sku is a text column, then you need to include quotes, I suggest single quotes and this will work:

```
If IsNull((DLookup("Sku", "Table1", "Sku = '" & me.Text2 & "'")) Then
```